# Return the results of one cell containing a formula into another cell so that cell only shows a value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code my spreadsheet to react to changes to a specific cell in my spreadsheet. This cell contains a formula so the programing is not recognizing any change to the cell although the number is updating the formula is not. I am looking for a way to return the results of the cell containing the formula into another cell as a value so the change can be recognized by the code.

Comment: If you use a worksheet_calculate event handler you can monitor your cell from that.  Eg see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44127072/478884

Comment: Could you share the formula and explain **which cells containing values** in which worksheet of which workbook make the formula change the result? Depending on this information, there still may be a `Worksheet_Change` solution using [Range.Precedents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents). Also, please share your current code even if it is `Worksheet_Change`. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73160420/edit) at any time.

Answer (score 0):

The change event isn't firing because the contents of the cell aren't changing, just what it displays (the formula result) is. You *could* use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event and check the value against another static value. If it's changed, then update it and trigger your other code.

It sounds like there's a better way to design your sheet though.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim watchCell As Range ' set to something
    Dim checkCell As Range ' set to something
    
    If checkCell.Value = watchCell.Value Then Exit Sub
    
'   Value has changed. Update the check and trigger action.
    checkCell.Value = watchCell.Value
    Call SomeOtherResponse
End Sub
```